# Cronjob send email but image cannot be displayed

Tags: php, cron, phpmailer

I have create a `test2.php` with a **phpmailer**. When I run this `PHP` in a browser, I can receive an email with an embedded image.

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage("dedicated.png", "logoimg", "dedicated.png");
$mail->Body = "<h1>Test 1 of PHPMailer html</h1>
    <p>This is a test picture: <img src=\"cid:logoimg\" /></p>";
$mail->AltBody="This is text only alternative body.";
```

But when i set a cronjob, I still receive an email, but the image cannot be displayed.

```
* * * * *  root php /var/www/html/work/test.php
```

Comment: Check the return value of `addEmbeddedImage()` - it will return true if it succeeds in locating the file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a path problem - cron jobs do not set a PATH environment var by default, so you have to set a path in your cron job, or use absolute paths for everything.

For example if you say:

```
php myscript.php
```

It may not find the php binary or your script, or your attachment, so you can try something like this:

```
PATH=/usr/bin
php myscript.php
```

or

```
/usr/bin/php /path/to/myscript.php
```

Comment: ya, i already set the path but the image still cannot display properly